# One-Hot-Encode two categorical variables with 3-levels each in sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, scikit-learn, dummy-variable

I have to encode two categorical variables `A` (levels=`A1`, `A2`, `A3`) and `B` (levels=`B1`, `B2`, `B3`) into dummy variables. My understanding is that `OneHotEncoder` in `sklearn` would encode my variables like, `A1` + `A2` + `A3` + `B1` + `B2` + `B3` = 2 (aka one-of-K scheme). Would that approach cause problems such as collinearity during fitting a model?

And why doesn't `sklearn` offer the option of K-1 encoding in the same way `pandas.get_dummies` does with `drop_first=True`? Or, am I missing something?

Comment: Just wondering why you don't want to use `pandas.get_dummies(data, columns =  cat_cols, drop_first=True)`?

Comment: That's because I need to integrate the whole preprocessing inside the `sklearn`'s API, you know, the `Pipeline` and `FeatureUnion` kind of things.

Comment: You can always extend the `OneHotEncoder` to make the changes in the returned data as you like. This custom class will be supported by the scikit Pipeline and FeatureUnion.